# How do I obtain firebase UserID in php?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I am going through Algolia document for generating Secure API Keys. Please see document https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/security/api-keys/secured-api-keys/how-to-restrict-the-search-to-a-subset-of-records-belonging-to-a-specific-user/.

I am using javascript but the documentation listed the codes below as a php file.

```
   $index->setSettings([
   'attributesForFaceting' => [
   'filterOnly(viewable_by)'
   ]
   ]);
```

and this

```
   $index->partialUpdateObject(
[
    'viewableBy' => [1, 2],
    'objectID' => 'myID1'
]
 );
```

and then this

```
  $currentUserID = 1; // Replace by the current user ID

 $securedApiKey = $client->generateSecuredApiKey(
'YourSearchOnlyApiKey', // Make sure to use a search key
  [
'filters' => 'viewable_by:'.$currentUserID
 ]
);
```

first of all I know firebase.auth().currentUser.uid is used to obtain the firebase user ID in javascript, how would I obtain the "currentUserID" in PhP and how do I connect my php file to my JS file?

Answer (score 0):

first, secured API keys needs to be generated on your backend using one of our client. Then, you can use this secured API key in the front-end client.

In the link you provided, the backend client is in PHP, but you could use the JS one instead. You can find a better example here:

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/api-keys/#generate-key

Hope that helps!